# Getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I need to implement the email task for my application. Right now just to get a hang of how things work in the mail task I created a simple process where I am just sending emails for this, I have a service task, which is configured to sending emails. I am getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate` when running the task.

Any idea on how to resolve the class not found error ?

Comment: In what context are you trying to use that class? Are you developing for the Alfresco ECM product or the Alfresco Activiti server? This particular class is only available in the former and not applicable to the latter.

Comment: I am using Alfresco Activiti Enterprise BPM Suite v1.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the classpath for your java files or for your jar packages

like export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path to java files

Comment: how do i set the classpath for the jar files ? And which jar needs to be added for AlfrescoScriptDelegate ?

Comment: This answer is a bit presumptive. You shouldn't need to set any classpath if you develop for the Alfresco ECM product - everything that is needed is already included in the web application and its classpath.

Comment: I am using Alfresco Activiti Enterprise BPM Suite v1.3.3. If everything is already added in the web application, then why am I getting this error ? Any pointers ??